# Why cannot delete from a table with reference to another

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, constraints

I have looked for answers but maybe I miss something.
I have 2 tables see below. The entities from the first table is referenced from the second one, but when I try to delete from the second I get `Error: foreign key mismatch`. There are triggers (not show here), but they have nothing to do with `DELETE` or `cmdauth`. I do not understand why cannot remove row?

```
CREATE TABLE app (name TEXT, script TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(name));
CREATE TABLE env (name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(name));
CREATE TABLE role (name TEXT, command TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(name,command));

CREATE TABLE cmdauth (groupname TEXT, rolename TEXT, appname TEXT, envname TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (appname) REFERENCES app(name), FOREIGN KEY (rolename) REFERENCES role(name), FOREIGN KEY (envname) REFERENCES env(name), PRIMARY KEY (groupname,rolename,appname,envname));

sqlite> select * from cmdauth where appname='app1' and groupname='admin' and envname='test' and rolename='restarter';
admin|restarter|app1|test
sqlite> delete from cmdauth where appname='app1' and groupname='admin' and envname='test' and rolename='restarter';
Error: foreign key mismatch
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) says:

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index.

This requirement is not met for the reference to `role(name)`.

Comment: Thank you, this was my fault. I was wondering how could I insert the data into `cmdauth`...maybe I haven't user `foreign_keys = ON` pragma.